# How can I get my ban removed if I cannot edit my (deleted) answers to improve them?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, post-ban

The posting system says that Stack Overflow is not accepting answers from my account any more, and it is suggested that I go back and fix my answers. I had initially posted to say I am still having that problem even with the suggested approach (which wasn't a real fix) in an answer (yea, my bad).

Later on I have actually fixed the problem, so I wanted to edit my answer- however it is said to be deleted by the moderators and even though I edit it, it won't show up. So, how can I get my ban removed if I cannot edit those answers to improve them?

This is the question: *[Wing IDE not stopping at break point for Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35457300/wing-ide-not-stopping-at-break-point-for-google-app-engine?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you edited your most recent answer after it was deleted and since it now appears to be an answer, I've undeleted it. I don't suppose this will happen for you in the future, but for other people who might get into the same bind, you should be able to [flag your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228288/should-1-reputation-users-be-able-to-flag-their-own-posts) to let a moderator know you've fixed the problem.